# Send esign request in docusign api by sending only few doc of a template

Tags: docusignapi

We have a template in DocuSign which is having 5 documents, now we want to send signing requests through the email in which we want to send only 2 or 3 documents of the template.

We are using DocuSign node js sdk

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a few different ways.

One approach is using [composite templates](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/), where the documents can be added separately from a template. The template still includes the recipients and tabs as needed.

Another approach is by having different templates with 2-3 documents you need. You can have as many templates as you need and use the one that fits you situations.

Comment: can we download template document and use that while creating the envelop ?

Comment: make a GET to that endpoint if you know the templateId and documentId:
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents/{documentId}

Comment: (from the node SDK you use templatesAPI object)